# How to use SignalR Stream in ASP.NET Core Angular app?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I tried to use SignalR stream to send real-time data to client and then display the data on Angular component's template.

Here is my code snippet, this function is bound to a button (click) event in the template:

```
    getMessage(message: string) {
    this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/messageHub').build();
    const connect = this.connection;

    connect.start().then(function () {
      connect.stream('SendMessage', message).subscribe({
        next: (item) => {
          console.log(item);   // <= this works: I can get the data from server
          let li = document.createElement("li"); // <= works
          li.textContent = item; // <= works
          document.getElementById("ulId").appendChild(li); // <= does not work, cannot get dom element by Id....
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log("finished.");
        },
        error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

I can't make it to work and will appreciate it if someone can provide me a working example.

Thanks, 
Jack

Comment: Instead of creting new li element here try to use li  with*ngFor  and keep arrary of message/item and every next interation just push into array. Angular will create new li element for you.

Comment: The problem here is that I can't pass the item values to DOM element. for example: if replacing li.textContent = item; by this.values.add(item); we can then binding values to li element with *ngFor. However,  this.values.add(item); statement is not valid here. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` Code be like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" id="startStreaming" value="Send" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>
```

`.JS` code be like this :

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("/streaming")
                .build();
    var button = document.getElementById("startStreaming");
    function startStreaming(){
        connection.stream("StartStreaming").subscribe({
            next: onStreamReceived,
            err: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            },
            complete: function(){
                console.log("finished streaming");
            }
        });
    }
    connection.on("streamStarted", function(){
        startStreaming();
    });
    button.addEventListener("click", event => {
        connection.invoke("sendStreamInit");
    });
    function onStreamReceived(data){
        console.log("received: " + data);
        var liElement = document.createElement('li');
        liElement.innerHTML = '<strong>' + "received" + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data;
        document.getElementById('discussion').appendChild(liElement);
    }
    connection.start();
```

You might be looking for this :

https://radu-matei.com/blog/signalr-core/#streaming

https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-samples/blob/master/streaming/web/wwwroot/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read these links before and made it works in a non-Angular app. Now, I just want to implement it in a way using TypeScript and data-binding in an Angular app, such as <button (click)="getMessage(...)">start</button>

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your class `messages: string[];` . Update your click event

```
 getMessage(message: string) {
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/messageHub').build();
const connect = this.connection;

connect.start().then(function () {
  connect.stream('SendMessage', message).subscribe({
    next: (item) => {
      this.messages.push(item);
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log("finished.");
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
})
```

}

Now set your html something like this

`<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages">
  </li>
</ul>`

Now on wards for each signalR iteration your new data will be pushed into messages array and it will update in html as well.

Comment: I tried it before. It gave an error message: Connection disconnected with error 'TypeError: cannot read property 'messages' of undefined'. why we can't use this.messages.push(item); statement? This works for a non-Angular app, why it does not work for an Angular app?

Comment: Found good example here. https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2